# Getting com error in SSRS saying RR]]rrRenderingError

Tags: reporting-services

I had a report that suddenly stopped working with the message that it had a problem rendering the report. I could not find an issue so I decided to try recreate the report- but even a blank report, when pressing run, returns the same error. Anyone know what could be causing this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: whats the full error, when you click 'details' ?

Comment: Just a rehash of the what is shown on screen, nothing extra. I did look in the event viewer, and that seems to be showing a missing Sol, just cannot locate which one it is

Comment: i would probably repair/reinstall report builder and/or your latest .net framework. Hard to give anymore advice without knowing more.

Comment: Yeah, my suspicion as well but trying to avoid that until I am sure there is no other option